In group descending rolling averages using dplyr
I need to calculate variations of rolling averages by group (group_by) in R dplyr.
The variation is that I want to calculate "descending" rolling averages, which means a rolling average including the 1 to N, then 2 to N, then 3 to N, up to N to N data points within the column of each group.
A simple example:
the_df <- tibble(id=c(rep('x', 11),rep('y',11)), a=rep(10:0,2), b=rep(seq(100,0, ,by=-10),2))

the_df <- the_df %>% 
          group_by(id) %>% 
          mutate(lead_time = row_number(), 
                 inverse_lead_time = 11-lead_time)

the_df %>%
  arrange(id, (lead_time)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(a,b), list(run_avg = ~ zoo::rollmean(., lead_time, fill = NA, align='left')))

The align='left' is included so the rolling average runs to the end of the group.
But, I'm not getting the output I expect.
The output of the last statement is:

In this case, I expect the column "a_run_avg" to increase with lead_time.
To reiterate, what I want is at lead_time = 5 (for example) the running average to be the average of column a to include all values a between lead_time = 5 and lead_time = 10.
The rolling average for lead_time=6 would include all values of a between lead_time = 6 and lead_time = 10.
The value of a_run_avg when lead_time = 1  should be 5.  Its the average of all values in the a column for the group.
The value of a_run_avg when lead_time = 10 should be 10.   I.e., is a rolling mean of only one value.
How can the example code be modified to achieve my descending rolling average?

Am abit confused on the run_average when lead_time=10. How is it 10? are there not two values ie 10 and 9? You have 11 elements and not 10 since you have 10:0. what about when the lead_time is 11?? is that not factored?

A mistake on my part.  You are correct.

In that case use rev(cummean(rev(.x)))

1) rollapply rollmean does not accept vector widths but rollapply does.
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

the_df %>%
  mutate(
     across(
      .cols = any_of(c("a", "b")), 
      .fns = ~ rollapply(.x, n():1, mean, align = "left"),
      .names = "avg_{.col}"
     ), .by = id)

giving
# A tibble: 22 × 5
   id        a     b avg_a avg_b
   <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 x        10   100   5      50
 2 x         9    90   4.5    45
 3 x         8    80   4      40
 4 x         7    70   3.5    35
 5 x         6    60   3      30
 6 x         5    50   2.5    25
 7 x         4    40   2      20
 8 x         3    30   1.5    15
 9 x         2    20   1      10
10 x         1    10   0.5     5
# ℹ 12 more rows

2) cummean dplyr has a cummean function so this would also work
library(dplyr)

the_df %>%
  mutate(
     across(
      .cols = any_of(c("a", "b")), 
      .fns = ~ rev(cummean(rev(.x))),
      .names = "avg_{.col}"
     ), .by = id)

Note
The input used
library(tibble)
the_df <- tibble(id=c(rep('x', 11),rep('y',11)),
  a=rep(10:0,2), b=rep(seq(100,0, ,by=-10),2))


This is it!  Thanks for your solution.   I also need to retain the "lead_time" column.
My initial run threw and error message that "Error in mutate():
! Can't supply .by when .data is a grouped data frame.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred."
Solved by using the_df %>% ungroup() %>%

fooavg <- function(x) {
  (sum(x) - cumsum(lag(x, default = 0))) / (length(x):1)
}

the_df |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(avg_a = fooavg(a), avg_b = fooavg(b))

#    id        a     b avg_a avg_b
#    <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 x        10   100   5      50
#  2 x         9    90   4.5    45
#  3 x         8    80   4      40
#  4 x         7    70   3.5    35
#  5 x         6    60   3      30
#  6 x         5    50   2.5    25
#  7 x         4    40   2      20
#  8 x         3    30   1.5    15
#  9 x         2    20   1      10
# 10 x         1    10   0.5     5
# ℹ 12 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

